# How to cross-references sections in a thesis?

Tags: thesis, writing-style, cross-referencing

When using cross-references in a thesis for cross-referencing to specific sections, do we have to use section numbers or section names would be fine too?

example:

> As discussed in the Discussion section, ...

vs

> As discussed in section 3.4, ...

If possible, please answer with a **citable reference**.

I remember reading that both are correct, but know I cannot find it! I think it was in the book "How to write a better thesis?" by Evans, Gruba and Zobel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, it's a matter of taste.  Both are indeed correct.

> As discussed in *the Discussion section/Section 3.4*

But the former is less usable, because finding *the Discussion section* is harder than finding *Section 3.4*, so **I strongly advocate the latter**.

Comment: I agree, but would also advise that the OP check any specific regulations their institution might have with regards to thesis formatting.

Comment: @user2768 Thanks! Of course, as I mentioned, I am looking for a citable reference. Because it seems my thesis reviewer haven't found many issues, and instead directed me to change the whole cross-reference styling!

Comment: @RFNO Which style have they suggested?

Comment: @user2768 I have used the first style (Alphabetical -> Discussion section) in my thesis, but the reviewer asked to me change all of them to the second one (Numeral one -> Section 3.4). If I was using Latex, I would have changed it right away, but as you know, cross-referencing is not Microsoft Word's strongest suit and they don't go hand in hand! Right now that I have a 200 page document, even simple meddling with cross-references, breaks the document in multiple places!

Comment: @RFNO Although this is a matter of taste, your style is rather unusable, which is why your thesis reviewer has directed you to change it. How has the direction been issued? Are you required to make the change or is it merely a suggestion or ...?

Comment: @user2768 I have to change it, but my supervisor told me it is not obligatory in his mind and we should push back! He also sent me some links to cite and not change the style, because he thinks the reviewer has made unfair comments when he could have just let it go! But the links my supervisor has sent are mostly regarding styles of 'table of contents' and not 'cross-referencing'! May I ask why is it unusable?

Comment: @RFNO I agree with your supervisor: It isn't necessary and you should push back. Personally, I'd suggest you explain the lessons you've learned. Regarding, _why is it [rather] unusable?_, because every reference is indirect (see reference, look-up section in contents, visit section), rather than direct (see reference, visit section).